# Move a Parent Element into a Sibling?

Tags: jquery

I need to move a parent anchor to wrap a child image more "closely". A simplified version of my HTML is:

```
<a class="link">
  <span class="container">
    <img class="image" />
    <span>An image caption.</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

I'm looking for this result:

```
<span class="container">
  <a class="link">
    <img class="image" />
  </a>
  <span>An image caption.</span>
</span>
```

I tried:

```
/* I have to process each anchor individually and only make 
 * this move if there's a span.container as the first child.
 */
$('a.link').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children('span.container').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('img.image').wrap($(this));
    $(this).children('span.container').unwrap();
  }
});
```

I end up with:

```
<span class="container">
  <a class="link">
    <span class="container">
      <img class="image">
        <img class="image" />
      </img>
      <span>An image caption.</span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <span>An image caption.</span>
</span>
```

Caveats: I'm n00b. I'm stuck with jQuery 1.3.2. I'm using [an `unwrap()` plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-unwrap-plugin/), which seems to be working as seen above. The problem is with my `wrap($(this))` I think? `$(this)` should only contain `<a class="link">` and not its children right? It seems to contain the children, they're inserted in the wrap, and I get duplicate HTML. Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.link').each(function(){
    var $me = $(this);
    $me.children('.container').unwrap().find('img').wrap($me);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm7RK/)